# Documentation for TS generic "string" syntax

Tags: typescript, addeventlistener, typescript-generics

This syntax compiles and works as intended:

```
window.addEventListener("keydown", this.handlerKeyDown, false);
...
this.handlerKeyDown = (evt => {
        let ke = evt as KeyboardEvent;
        console.log("handlerKeyDown saw", ke.key);            
        return false;
    });
```

but it requires the cast to KeyboardEvent.

I notice that when I hover the addEventListener method, the tip says

```
(method) Window.addEventListener<"keypress">(type: "keypress", 
listener: (this: Window, ev: KeyboardEvent) => any, 
options?: boolean | AddEventListenerOptions | undefined): void (+1 overload)
```

I'd really prefer a strongly typed signature that doesn't require the cast but I've had the devil of a time finding documentation for this syntax.

Attempting to guess, I note that the `Window.addEventListener<"keypress">(` syntax doesn't upset my compiler but I can't figure out what it wants for the lambda expression defining the listener.

Can anyone explain it with an example or provide the right search terms?

One of the things puzzling me is how to control whether the event is consumed. The definition for EventListener is

```
interface EventListener {
    (evt: Event): void;
}
```

As per Basarat's answer I've tried to specify a stronger signature but that was incompatible with the EventListener interface, which is why I was looking at the definition already posted above.

Emboldened by the fact that Basarat came up with the exact same approach, I tried this

```
    this.handlerKeyDown = (ke: Event | KeyboardEvent) => {
        if (ke instanceof KeyboardEvent) {
            console.log("handlerKeyDown saw", ke.key);
            if (this.router && ke.key === "Esc") {
                this.router.navigateBack();
            }
            return true;
        }
    };
```

which no longer upsets the compiler, but it's not a huge improvement on the cast.

Comment: `listener: (this: Window, ev: KeyboardEvent) => any` is a function that accepts a single parameter of `KeyboardEvent`, returns anything and is having `this` typed as `Window` inside a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'd really prefer a strongly typed signature that doesn't require the cast

Add an annotation:

```
this.handlerKeyDown = (evt: KeyboardEvent => {
```

## More

The compiler will infer it if you had it inline:

```
window.addEventListener("keydown", (e /* type will be inferred */) => {});
```

Comment: That's what I tried to do, but then I can't assign it to this.handlerKeyDown which I need in order to remove it later.

Comment: Then just add the annotation as described 

Comment: I'm going to accept this answer even though the outcome doesn't greatly improve my code, because you've answered the question and helped me reach certainty about my options.